# Trying to identify a baby bird seen in Palermo, Sicily

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

I'm trying to identify a baby bird that i saw in a pond in Palermo, Sicily, Italy. Unfortunately i did not see any parents!
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks,
Robert[image: baby bird photo]

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the chick of a Moorhen (*Gallinula chloropus*) or Coot (*Fulica atra*), probably the former. Both species are common on ponds.

Comment: The moorhen chicks on the picture here indeed have this similar German/Belgian flag coloured beak: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Gallinula_chloropus_-Regents_Park%2C_London%2C_England_-chicks-8.jpg

Answer (score 2):

it's a chick of Common Moorhen. Shape and color of the bill allow to tell it apart from the coot's one.

Also the behaviour can help: the moorhen often walks on floating vegetation whereas the coots prefer to swim.